# C++ array is overwriting every element with current value from loop

Tags: arrays, pipe, parent

I'm very confused about something.  I have a loop that is reading back values from a child process and inserting them into a char array (called sleepTime). I'm getting the correct values back (I display them in the console immediately after putting them into my char array) but when the loop reads the next value, everything in the array is updated to the current value read back from the pipe.  After exiting the loop I've printed the results again and every element of the array is the last read value.  Can anyone shed light on this?  I'm very stumped.

```
char* sleepTime[4];
char randNumSend[15];
char randNumRet[15];
for (int i=0; i<nWorkers; i++){ // loop to read back values from child process
    read(pipe2[0],randNumRet,strlen(randNumSend));  // read back data
    sleepTime[i]=randNumRet; // save values as string for execlp command
    cout << "sleepTime" << i+1 << ": " << sleepTime[i]<< endl;
}

close(pipe2[0]);    // close read end of pipe2

for (int i =0; i<nWorkers; i++){
    cout << "sleepTime" << i+1 << ": " << sleepTime[i]<< endl;
}
```

Comment: how is `sleepTime` declared?

Comment: Can we see where you declared **randNumRet**, **randNumSend**, and **sleepTime**?

Comment: i added the variable declarations for sleepTime, randNumSend, and randNumRet at the top of my code.

Answer (score 0):

`char* sleepTime[4];` is an array of pointers.

If you write to `sleepTime[i]` you are writing to **unallocated** memory.  This is an error.

To allocate you can loop through your array and do:

```
sleepTime[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * length_of_string);
```

Then don't forget to do the same with `free(sleepTime[i]);` in order to avoid leaks.

In C++ use `std::string` instead.

Usage:

```
std::string foo = "blah blah";

std::string bar;  

bar = "blah blah";
```

Comment: later in the code I'm running an execlp() command with sleepTime elements as args.  It kept giving me errors until I made the array a char*.  I think there's something fundamental here that I'm missing.  I'm very new to C++.

Comment: `exceclp(const char*)` expects a `const char*` and if you don't have one, you pass the address of the variable `char f = 'a'; exceclp(&a);`, but seeing you have an array of pointers, you can just do `exceclp(sleepTime[i]);`

Comment: I'm not sure how to use std::string

Answer (score 0):

the values in sleep time all point to the same array. i suggest trying sleeptime[4][15] and replace randNumRet with sleeptime[ i ] ( in the read function )